# Garbage printed with string after strcpy

Tags: c, struct, strcpy, garbage

I am a beginner in C and I am trying to copy a string inside another one. I have the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
    float mort_2009, mort_2015, indices;
    char estado[];
} Mortalidade;

void defineEstados (
    Mortalidade *e, 
    char estado[],
    float mort_2009,
    float mort_2015,
    int posix)
{
    strcpy(e[posix].estado, estado);
    e[posix].mort_2009 = mort_2009;
    e[posix].mort_2015 = mort_2015;
    e[posix].indice = mort_2009 / mort_2015;
}

void imprimeEstados (Mortalidade *e){
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        printf("Estado: %s, Morte em 2009: %.1f, Morte em 2015: %.1f, Indice: %.2f \n",
            e[i].estado,
            e[i].mort_2009,
            e[i].mort_2015,
            e[i].indice);
    }
}

int main() {

    Mortalidade estados[27];

    defineEstados(estados, "AC", 12.6, 10.6, 0);
    defineEstados(estados, "AL", 12.6, 10.6, 1);
    defineEstados(estados, "AP", 12.6, 10.6, 2);
    
    imprimeEstados(estados);
    return 0;
}
```

My struct `Mortalidade` has a field called `estado`, which will receive a string (and other data) in the void function `defineEstados`. Therefore, after copying the string inside the struct using `strcpy`, in the void function `imprimeEstados`, when I want to print the `estados` inside my struct, the result seems like garbage inside the variable, and I don't know how to find the error. Here is the output obtained:

```
Estado: ��IA��)A�&�?��IA��)A�&�?AP, Morte em 2009: 12.6, Morte em 2015: 10.6, Indice: 1.19 
Estado: ��IA��)A�&�?AP, Morte em 2009: 12.6, Morte em 2015: 10.6, Indice: 1.19 
Estado: AP, Morte em 2009: 12.6, Morte em 2015: 10.6, Indice: 1.19
```

Speaking personally seems like garbage concatenated, but I don't know how to fix it.

Note: I pretend to insert more `estados`, but I prefer to fix the code previously.

Comment: how many chars can you store in estado? How big is it?

Comment: The `Mortalidade` type has a flexible array member. It only makes sense to have an array of *pointers* to the `struct` instances that have been allocated with sufficient memory. Having an array of `struct` will only work if its array member `estado` is a pointer, and *that* is allocated sufficient memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
typedef struct {
    float mort_2009, mort_2015, indices;
    char estado[];
} Mortalidade;
```

`estado` is a flexible array member having length zero (0). You cant use this struct the way you use it in your program as static allocation will not allocate any memory for it.

This kind of struct is intended to be used with **dynamic** allocation.

```
typedef struct {
    float mort_2009, mort_2015, indices;
    char estado[];
} Mortalidade;

void defineEstados (
    Mortalidade **e, 
    char estado[],
    float mort_2009,
    float mort_2015,
    int posix)
{
    e[posix] = malloc(sizeof(**e) + strlen(estado) + 1);
    if(e[posix])
    {
        strcpy(e[posix] -> estado, estado);
        e[posix] -> mort_2009 = mort_2009;
        e[posix] -> mort_2015 = mort_2015;
        e[posix] -> indices = mort_2009 / mort_2015;
    }
}

void imprimeEstados (Mortalidade **e){
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        if(e[i]) printf("Estado: %s, Morte em 2009: %.1f, Morte em 2015: %.1f, Indice: %.2f \n",
            e[i] -> estado,
            e[i] -> mort_2009,
            e[i] -> mort_2015,
            e[i] -> indices);
    }
}

int main() {

    Mortalidade *estados[27];

    defineEstados(estados, "AC", 12.6, 10.6, 0);
    defineEstados(estados, "AL", 12.6, 10.6, 1);
    defineEstados(estados, "AP", 12.6, 10.6, 2);
    
    imprimeEstados(estados);
    //free memory
    return 0;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/13j31hGeG

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you declared a structure with a flexible array member named `estado`

```
typedef struct {
    float mort_2009, mort_2015, indices;
    char estado[];
} Mortalidade
```

It has an incomplete character array type.

You need either to allocate memory for the data member along with an object of the structure type or to specify a fixed size of the array or declare the data member as a pointer of the type `char *` and allocate memory for a stored string.

The simplest way is just tp declare the data member `estado` like

```
    char estado[3];
```

It is enough to store your string literals.

Comment: I tried to make char estado[2], but it did not work as well...

Comment: @GuilhermeHepfener String literals like this "AC" have the type char[3]. So you need to declare the array as having the type at least char[3] if you want to use the function strcpy to copy the whole string literal in a character array.

Comment: @GuilhermeHepfener To be more specific, count the number of characters (letters) in your string first, add 1 to it and then use it as the `char[]` array size. For example, `"ABC"` would be a `char[4]`.

Comment: It has complete character array type. This type is called flexible array member and if has well defined length of 0

Comment: @0___________ It is a declaration of incomplete array type.:) From the C Standard "18 As a special case, the last element of a structure with more than one named member may
have an incomplete array type; this is called a flexible array member" If you do not specify the number of elements in an array declaration that does not have an initializer then the array has incomplete type.